# how to use the groovy controller element in JavaScript

Tags: grails, gsp

I have

```
def exception = request.exception.stackTraceLines
```

in Groovy controller. How can I get the value of the `exception` in the JavaScript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are adding exception to your return like this.

```
flash.message = message(exception: 'Error: xxx');
```

you can get it like this

```
<div class="message" role="status"> ${flash.message} </div>
```

just use ${ your flash.your_var_name}

Answer (score 1):

You have multiple options to fix this. When using javascript I usually use a wrapper which can hold the error message/stacktrace. It depends on where and how you want to do the error handling. Example:

```
def book = new Book(params)
book.validate()

render (contentType: "text/json") {[
    "data": book,
    "errors": book.hasErrors() ? book.errors : null
]}
```

Then you can check if "errors" has a value when getting back your JSON to determine if there are errors in the input for instance. (Elvis operator probably works too, book.errors ?: null) Other (uncatched) exceptions I handle in the error callback I usually define in my JavaScript. (jQuery mostly, (with malsup jquery.form.js in this case))

```
$(function() {
  $("form").live("submit", function() {
    $(this).ajaxSubmit({
      error: function (msg) {
        /* Catch hard errors here (500's) */
        alert("Error occurred: " + msg);
      },
      success: function(wrapper) {
         if (wrapper.errors != null) {
            /* Handle model errors here */
         } else {
            /* Parse data here */
            var book = wrapper.data;
         }
      }
    });
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this

```
render(template:"book",model:[book:theBook, exception:exception])
```

Or like this (didnt try, don't know if works)

```
render(template:"book",model:[book:theBook, exception:exception!=null?exception:""])
```

and then access from the GSP like this

```
${exception.getMessage()}
```